# How to overlay div over another div without using z-index and position : absolute

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs as shown in following code. I want to overlay "secondDiv" on "firstDiv". My HTML template will be dynamically loaded. So position of the divs on the screen can't be determined. I can't use `z-index` and `position: absolute` as it disturbs all the layout.

```
<div id="firstDiv" style= "height=54px;width=96px"></div>
<div id="secondDiv"></div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You say you don't know the position of the divs on the screen. I assume you know that the second comes after the first? If that's the case, and they have the same z-index, does it not automatically overlay the first?

Comment: No, it doesnt. SecondDiv is shown below the first one.

Comment: I assume there is some other CSS that you have applied to each of the divs. Can you provide it, please?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you give a positioned element a z-index of -1 it will go beneath other content.  You don't need position absolute, RELATIVE positioning works for this which means that it will still be in the flow of your document AND be beneath other objects overlapping with it.

[This article is what you want to read for overlapping content nuances.](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex)  It focuses on z-index but also talks about stacking orders which is something you might consider leveraging.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div id="firstDiv" style="height:150px;width:150px">Hello</div>
<div id="secondDiv" style="position:absolute;height:50px;width:50px;background:rgb(255,0,0);left:9px;top:20px;">how r u</div>
```

Comment: Your code does work in the sample. But embedding it in my app does not seems to be possible as I dont know the exact positioning of my div. So that i cant use "top:20px" in any ways. I am using dynamically generated HTML template.

Answer (score 0):

Put both divs in another div with `position` set to `relative`, and you can use absolute positioning and z-index, and/or visibility controller by javascript.